# How to fetch data from jQuery function and append to img src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my JavaScript function where I am able to pull data from action method in JSON format:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
         $.getJSON("/Home/GetUsers", null, function (data) {
         var div = $('#ajaxDiv');
         div.html("<br /> " + "Users received from server: " + "<br />");
         $.each(data, function (i, item)
         {
          printUser(div, item);
            });
          });
        });
     function printUser(div, item)
     {
      div.append("<br/>" + "UserName: " + item.UserName + "<br/>" + "Id: " + item.Id);
      <img src="@Url.Action("GetFileData", "Home", new { id = item.Id })" style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>
     }      
  </script>
```

As you can see, I am able to get `item.Id`, but how do I send it into src tag new `{ id = item.Id }`
It is showing syntax error. I just want to show the image within this Ajax div. Please help me out.

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is razor code which is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. `item` is a javascript variable which does not even exist at that point (its not in scope). You need to manually build the url. But why not just return the file path in the json data?

Comment: okk i will manually build the url path and pass it into json data but then i will get error at how to display it onto view page @StephenMuecke

Comment: What error? If you pass the correct url, it just needs to be `<img scr=" + item.url + " style="...." />` where `item.url` might be say `"~/Images/myimage.png"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke okk i am going to use url but i will definitly get some error let me try

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have got the url but how to pass in img src attribute I have tried something like this: div.append("<img src= + item. />"); but its not working should i post a new question ??

Comment: Yes you need to post a new question.